# What does the "Empty srcset[]" breakpoint in Picture Module?

Tags: media, theming

I'm using the Picture Module.

What does the `Empty srcset []` breakpoint exactly do? Why should I use it, and why shouldn't I use?

Answer (score 1):

The empty srcset is to be used when there is a breakpoint where you don't want to display your image. An example might be where the image in question, or a parent div, is `display:none` in the css. The image would normally be downloaded anyway, but by having an empty srcset at that breakpoint, no images will be downloaded.